# Maximum call stack size exceeded when binding FullCalendar in Aurelia app

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack, fullcalendar, aurelia

I am trying to initialize a JQuery plugin ([FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/typescript)) inside my Aurelia, TypeScript-driven app. I am new to web developement and just trying to get a minimal example to work. I used [this template](https://github.com/MaximBalaganskiy/AureliaDotnetTemplate) as the starting point.

I followed a structure suggested in [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/Scapal/6e54b08b1de8c7aa6da9). I seem to be able to at least get to initialisation, but then some kind of infinite recursion/loop keeps calling my constructor:

```
    aurelia-logging-console.js:47 ERROR [app-router] Error: Error invoking calendar. Check the inner error for details.
------------------------------------------------
Inner Error:
Message: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Inner Error Stack:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Container._get (http://localhost:6213/dist/vendors~app.js?v=5idOSe8epNjIdNWRygcEushmRuUc29hR3OzFxAbI6T8:6683:43)
    at Container._get (http://localhost:6213/dist/vendors~app.js?v=5idOSe8epNjIdNWRygcEushmRuUc29hR3OzFxAbI6T8:6691:26)
    at Container._get (http://localhost:6213/dist/vendors~app.js?v=5idOSe8epNjIdNWRygcEushmRuUc29hR3OzFxAbI6T8:6691:26)
    at Container._get (http://localhost:6213/dist/vendors~app.js?v=5idOSe8epNjIdNWRygcEushmRuUc29hR3OzFxAbI6T8:6691:26)
    at Container._get (http://localhost:6213/dist/vendors~app.js?v=5idOSe8epNjIdNWRygcEushmRuUc29hR3OzFxAbI6T8:6691:26)
    at Container._get (http://localhost:6213/dist/vendors~app.js?v=5idOSe8epNjIdNWRygcEushmRuUc29hR3OzFxAbI6T8:6691:26)
    at Container._get (http://localhost:6213/dist/vendors~app.js?v=5idOSe8epNjIdNWRygcEushmRuUc29hR3OzFxAbI6T8:6691:26)
    at Container._get (http://localhost:6213/dist/vendors~app.js?v=5idOSe8epNjIdNWRygcEushmRuUc29hR3OzFxAbI6T8:6691:26)
    at Container._get (http://localhost:6213/dist/vendors~app.js?v=5idOSe8epNjIdNWRygcEushmRuUc29hR3OzFxAbI6T8:6691:26)
    at Container._get (http://localhost:6213/dist/vendors~app.js?v=5idOSe8epNjIdNWRygcEushmRuUc29hR3OzFxAbI6T8:6691:26)
End Inner Error Stack
```

The suggested fix of including as FullCalendar as `require from` also doesn't work, no matter if as `@inlineView` or directly in my View (html):

```
@inlineView('<template><require from="../../../../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css"></require><require from="../../../../node_modules/fullcalendar"></require></template>')
```

As I then get a following error from my ASP.Net service (seems to be WebPack configuration issue):

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:Error: C:\Users\***\AureliaDotnetTemplate\node_modules\aurelia-webpack-plugin\dist\PreserveModuleNamePlugin.js:145
throw new Error("PreserveModuleNamePlugin: Unable to find root of module " + name);
```

My ViewModel (calendar.ts):

```
import {
  autoinject, inject, bindable, bindingMode,
  customElement, BindingEngine
} from 'aurelia-framework';
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as moment from "moment";
import * as fullCalendar from 'fullcalendar';

@customElement('calendar')
@autoinject
export class calendar {
  @bindable weekends = true;
  @bindable dayClick;
  @bindable eventClick;
  @bindable events = [];
  @bindable options;
  @bindable view;
  subscription = null;
  calendar: any;

  constructor(private element: Element, private bindingEngine: BindingEngine) {

    this.subscription = this.bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.events).subscribe((splices) => { this.eventListChanged(splices) });
  }

  eventListChanged(splices) {
    if (this.calendar)
      this.calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
  }

  eventsChanged(newValue) {
    if (this.subscription !== null) {
      this.subscription.dispose();
    }
    this.subscription = this.bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.events).subscribe((splices) => { this.eventListChanged(splices) });

    if (this.calendar)
      this.calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
  }

  attached() {
    console.log('calendar attached');
    console.log(this.element);
    console.log($(this.element));

    this.calendar = $(this.element);
    let eventSource = (start, end, timezone, callback) => {
      callback(this.events);
    }

    let defaultValues = {
      defaultView: this.view || 'month',
      weekends: this.weekends,
      firstDay: 1,
      dayClick: (date, jsEvent, view) => this.dayClick(date, jsEvent, view),
      eventClick: (event) => this.eventClick(event),
      events: eventSource
    }

    this.calendar.fullCalendar(Object.assign(defaultValues, this.options));
  }
}
```

and my View (calendar.html):

```
<template>
    <h1>Calendar</h1>
    <calendar></calendar>
</template>
```

**EDIT:**
Following Rory's suggestion I tried to remove event handlers to show a minimal snippet, this did not help as I still get the same exception. I believe the problem is in binding?

```
import {
  autoinject, inject, bindable,
  customElement
} from 'aurelia-framework';
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as moment from "moment";
import * as fullCalendar from 'fullcalendar';

@autoinject
@customElement('calendar')
export class calendar {
  @bindable weekends = true;
  @bindable dayClick;
  @bindable eventClick;
  @bindable events = [];
  @bindable options;
  @bindable view;
  subscription = null;
  calendar: any;

  constructor(private element: Element) {}

  attached() {
    console.log('calendar attached');
    console.log(this.element);
    console.log($(this.element));

    this.calendar = $(this.element);
    let eventSource = (start, end, timezone, callback) => {
      callback(this.events);
    }

    let defaultValues = {
      defaultView: this.view || 'month',
      weekends: this.weekends,
      firstDay: 1,
      dayClick: (date, jsEvent, view) => this.dayClick(date, jsEvent, view),
      eventClick: (event) => this.eventClick(event),
      events: eventSource
    }

    this.calendar.fullCalendar(Object.assign(defaultValues, this.options));
  }
}
```

Comment: That error means you have created an infinite loop in your JS/TS. From the code you've shown I would guess that one of your 'event' handler function is itself raising an event and causing the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This much I realised, but I don't understand what exactly causes that and why (as suggested in the lined snippet) adding a "require" for css/root plugin root would help?

Comment: Checking the error again it appears the problem is in `vendors~app.js` - is that related to the calendar?

Comment: `vendors` was already included [in the template](https://github.com/MaximBalaganskiy/AureliaDotnetTemplate/blob/master/package-lock.json) i used, inside `package-lock.json`.

Comment: Just as an aside if you are "new to web developement and just trying to get a minimal example to work," then you need to stop and step back: Get your Aurelia app working, separate from ASP.NET. Try using the Aurelia CLI by itself and work through this issue. Adding ASP.NET to the mix might be useful for you down the road, but at this point, it's just adding unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @Ashley Grant: This is a fair point, but I feel quite comfortable with ASP.Net and backend development so being "new" means being new to web front-ends. So after I got some basic REST APIs I started to add some widgets to the front-end to display them. Apparently I did not understand binding fully, but there was still another problem with jQuery integration I managed to work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your calendar custom element template, you have another calendar custom element, which creates infinite loop of calendars. Im not sure what your intention is but easiest fix is change the calendar in the template to some other name

Comment: This is correct, I also figured out that my binding was wrong (I confused template names with property names in the ViewModel). However, even with the correct binding I could not get the example to work because of `Calendar is not a function` exception. It think it was connected to jQuery not being called/initialised correctly. However, I manged to avoid the problem altogether by using [an alpha v.4.0.0 version of FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/release-notes) which does not rely on jQuery.